# Is there any way to get the content of already fetched JavaScript/ CSS/ image of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, rendering, render

When the webpage gets loaded it fetches all the required dependency so is there any way we get the already fetched content and show it in console (without making another call to the server).

I tried the fetch() method by passing the `"force-cache"` option but it doesn't work always (e.g. what if the server sends in the header to not cache specific file).

Any idea about this?

Comment: Did you try service workers? Service workers monitors all your network requests and there you can write your code to cache the response. Take a look at this example of [service workers with caching.](https://github.com/nodexpertsdev/service-worker-cache-example/blob/master/www/service-worker.js)

Comment: Thanks @Lakshya for providing the inputs

Answer (score 1):

The `document` has all the info on it. So you can access `document.scripts`, `document.images`, `document.styleSheets`, etc.

This very page has this image, for example: [image: screenshot of dev tools on this page]

Comment: Yes but I am interested in the content not the resources name. For e.g. `document.scripts[2]
<script async src=​"https:​/​/​www.google-analytics.com/​analytics.js">​</script>​` is showing only the location but I need content of the script (without making a call)

Comment: In Chrome, if you hover over the link in a script tag and right click, it will give you an option to "Reveal in Sources panel" — which does not make a new network call but shows you the content of the already-fetched script.